# Lisp Recursion Not Calling Previous Functions

Tags: recursion, lisp, conditional-statements

I'm trying to have a function compare the first argument of a passed in argument to a value, then if it is true, perform some function, then recursively call the same function.

```
(defun function (expression)
  (cond
    ((equal (first expression) "+")
     (progn (print "addition")
            (function (rest expression))))))
```

For some reason, though, it is only going through it recursively and not printing. Thanks.

Comment: in Common Lisp, FUNCTION is a reserved symbol. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to say:

```
(defun function (expression)
  (cond (expression
         (cond (equal (first expression) "+")
               (print "addition")))
         (function (rest expression)))))
```

the original recurses only if (first expression) is "+"
and also fails to do a nil-check.

Comment: After reformatting you can immediately see that this will not work.  The error will be that the variable "equal" is not bound.

Comment: You're right, I dropped the "()" around the "(equal ...)".  Fingers were faster than brain.